# Bootstrap datepicker (multiple) unselect not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am working on a project where I need multiple years so I use Bootstrap datepicker with multiple date input

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy",
    multidate: true,
    minViewMode: 2
});

$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker('setDate', '2015','2016');
```

It works fine but when i click on selected date (here year) like **2015** than it append 2015 instead of deselect it.

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nmuuv4e7/)

Comment: try to change  multidate: true, to multidate: false

Comment: i need multiple years.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found solution after 2 days :) instead of **setDate** use  **setUTCDate** and have to pass all years in new Date to get full time

```
var myDate = [];
var data = ["2012","2016"];
$.each(data, function(k, v){
   var nd = new Date(v);
   var ndd = nd.getDate()-1;
   var ndm = nd.getMonth()+1;
   var ndy = nd.getFullYear();
   var ndg = [parseInt(ndy), parseInt(ndm), parseInt(ndd)];
   myDate.push(new Date(nd)); 
});
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker('setUTCDate',myDate);
```

**setDate** store current datetime(like **[Tue Sep 19 2017 11:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)]**

when we click on year in datepicker calendar it store time like **[Sun Jan 01 2012 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)]**

so both time stores different time thatswhy it doent deselect date we set using setDate