# how to unset single date from bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I have following bootstrap datepicker:

[image]

Now, when I am deleting the 24th date from my another table, as a result, it should remove the 24th date from the date picker after the ajax call.

I have written the following code for it. However, it's not working:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo VIEW_HOST_PATH;?>remove_data.php",
            data: {ch: ch, dh: dh, sp_rec: sp_rec, cartDate: 1},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);

                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                //console.log(obj.length);
                var selectedDates = '';
                for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
                    //selectedDates = selectedDates+"'"+obj[i]+"',";
                    //$('#disc_single_datepicker_1').datepicker('setDates',[obj[i]]);
                }
                console.log(selectedDates);
                //alert(selectedDates); 
                //$('#disc_single_datepicker_1').datepicker('setDates',[data]);
                //$('#disc_single_datepicker_1').datepicker('update',selectedDates);
                display_toastr(datainfo+" record has been removed!","Remove Record",true,"right","info");
                $("#row_"+dh).fadeOut('slow');

            }, error: function() {
                alert("Something went wrong. Please contact admin!");
            }
        });
```

so what should I write to unset that particular date. thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46315417/10634638

Comment: @bestinamir thanks but its still not working for my particular case as what I am trying to do is to unset the 24th date. Now,how I can convert and setUTCDate for 24/04/2020?

Comment: Try hardcoding this date to see if it works at all.

Comment: If you asking how to clear, one way is to clear everything then set what.

Comment: not working as getting error TypeError: a.getTime is not a function bootstrap-datepicker.min.js:7:9197

Comment: yeah, I think that's also fine to unset and then set again but I don't find any solution on that either.

Comment: Here they follow different format to set https://stackoverflow.com/q/25874375/10634638

Comment: Since the dates are toggle on/off may be you can fire a click event for specific date    https://stackoverflow.com/a/57383235/10634638

Comment: @bestinamir the following solution didn't work for me as I've tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874375/multiple-dates-in-bootstrap-date-picker

Comment: @bestinamir the following is also in no use:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175100/bootstrap-datepicker-trigger-change/57383235#57383235